# C++ Detecting USB serial device plugged/unplugged

Tags: linux, embedded, usb, hotplugging

I need to detect when a USB serial device is plugged or unplugged on my embedded system and know what is the `tty` associated with it.

My system runs over a 2.6 Linux Kernel.

Since I don't have write access to `udev` rules, nowadays I'm trying to get this information from the file system, looking for modifications in `/sys/bus/usb/devices` directory. However, I'm facing some problems with this approach.

I know what is the `Id BUS` of the USB port connected (e.g 1-1.3). So, I search for the associated `tty` (looking for a directory in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/<Id BUS>:1.0/tty/` - e.g. `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3:1.0/tty/ttyACM0`). This way I know that I should use `/dev/ttyACM0` to communicate with my device.
But, sometimes, this device (`/dev/ttyACM0`) does not exist.

Is there any better way to get this information?

I even thought trying to get this information from the syslog, but I don't know whether this is a pretty good idea.

Edit:

Only to clarify, my system needs to be able to detect state changes in the USB bus, i.e. detecting when a new device is plugged (and getting the `tty` name linked to it) or an existing one is unplugged.

The system is monitoring up to `N` USB/serial devices, which are plugged to it using an USB HUB. During its normal execution new devices can be plugged, existing devices can be removed (or rebooted by a remote command - out of this scope). When a device is rebooted, it could receive a different `tty` from the previous one used before (e.g. `ttyACM0` -> `ttyACM3`), since the kernel designates to it a `tty` which is free at the moment, and it is a big problem to me.

Answer (score 3):

[Netlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) is the preferred mechanism for communication between kernel and userspace.

You would create a Netlink socket with family `NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT`, listen on that socket and filter out messages that contain `SUBSYSTEM=usb` and `ACTION=add` for USB plug events or `ACTION=remove` for USB unplug events.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a USB abstraction library called [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp).  You should look at its [port_name example](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/master/examples/port_name/port_name.cpp), which shows how to use libusbp to get the serial port name (e.g. `/dev/ttyACM0`) for a USB serial device.  Behind the scenes, libusbp gets this information using libudev.

Comment: Thanks @david-grayson, I have edited the question, adding a better overview about the problematic scenario. Is it possible, using your lib, meet the described requirements?

Comment: the embedded system unfortunately doesn't have libudev, only mdev is present, so I cannot use your lib.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the virtual file is deleted using stat.

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

...

struct stat sb;
return (stat("/dev/ttyUSB0", &sb) == 0); // true if open, false otherwise
```